# JavaFX widthProperty not refreshing

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, properties, javafx

I am working on a javaFX project in which I need precise control over Node's size.
My code currently correctly updates the prefWidthProperty when needed, and the min and max size is set to use the pref size, yet the widthProperty is not updating.

I have verified this with print statements added as listeners to the properties. PrefWidthProperty updates, widthProperty does not (until I click the Node, possibly giving focus?)

I tried requesting layouts on both itself and its parent, same with focus, did not work.

I currently do not really know how to fix this bug which is very annoying. it seems that currently everything always lags 1 layout pass behind.

Code used to set the size and check for changes:

```
//Set the size
this.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
this.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
this.prefWidthProperty().bind(getTotalWidthProperty());

public ObservableValue<? extends Number> getTotalWidthProperty() {       
    return rightArgument.layoutXProperty().add(rightArgument.translateXProperty()).add(rightArgument.widthProperty()).add(H_GAP);
}

//Check for change:
this.prefWidthProperty().addListener(p -> System.out.println("FB_Pref_"+System.currentTimeMillis() + "  " + this.getPrefWidth()));
this.widthProperty().addListener(p -> System.out.println("FB______"+System.currentTimeMillis() + "  " + this.getWidth()));
```

As said before, the FB_Pref gets printed correctly on time, FB_____ gets printed way too late.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code please?

Comment: What parts would you like to see more? I have added some bits as to how I set the prefWidthProperty.

Answer (score 1):

If you set min/max to pref, this will create a fixed sized node. The min/max/pref sizes will be included during first layout phase. The width "property" reflects the currently set width on your node. So if you do not change the width, your listener will never get an event. You can sysout the width with getWidth, this always returns the current width.

There are two types of listeners in JavaFX, a changelistener and an invalidation listener. You added an invalidation listner with lambdas. This one fires only as needed and not at every change only on a relayout. Look here for more Information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#sthref12

Simply try this one:

```
this.prefWidthProperty().addListener(
        (ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
          System.out.println("FB_Pref_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "  " + this.getPrefWidth());
        });

this.widthProperty().addListener(
        (ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
          System.out.println("FB______" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "  " + this.getWidth())
        });
```

Comment: That sadly did not change anything for me :(
If possible I would want to set the widthProperty, but that is readonly so not possible. I had the idea to call the setWidth() method when prefWidthProperty changed, but this also had no effect.

Comment: How do you wanted  to change the prefWidth? Is it related to another node? The method setWidth does it's job on the widthProperty, so you are able to set it.

Comment: Okay, so setting the width on a prefWidthProperty change does trigger the widthProperty listener, and also updates the getWidth() of the Node. It does not however visually update the Node. Infact, it causes RunTimeExceptions, setting a bound value (which I did not directly touch). I have a feeling this is closing in on the real problem however...

Comment: I have a Node that contains elements on which the width is based, these can change alot, so I (wanted to) use binds to control the size. This Node in turns is contained in a StackPane, contained in a custom Controller. The StackPane also does not update its width.

Comment: Ah, you want that the components inside your stage are resizing, when your window is resized?

Comment: It not about the window being resized, the elements in the Node can change size or move based on user interaction, and in doing so the width of the containing Node needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Hm, can't image exactly. Can you please add a hierarchy of the components? Like in Scene Builder? And explain which component('s) will change and which one have to set it's new width, cause the containing nodes resized?

Answer (score 0):

This is a long delay to answering the question. I discovered a solution to this when I performed a similar binding task to a *prefWidthProperty* and *prefHeightProperty*. It does seem that the width/height of the node is one layout step behind the preferred dimension. Doing the following will solve it (assuming that **this** extends Node):

```
prefWidthProperty.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> getParent().requestLayout());
};
```

For some reason, executing the `Runnable` later on the `Application` thread works. Each time the preferred dimension is set, *requestLayout()* is called anyway inside the *invalidated()* method of `MinPrefMaxProperty` of the `Region` class. This is just forcing the update again.